# I am trying to get this input view to move up so it does not disappear when keyboard appears

Tags: swift, keyboard, constraints

I am trying to move my view up by accessing the bottomConstraint, and setting it equal to the height of the keyboard. I am not sure which constraint I should access in order to move the view up when the user is inputting text, Below is my two functions to show and hide the keyboard:

```
// MARK: Scroll View Resize on Keyboard Events
func setupViewResizerOnKeyboardShown() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowForResizing),
                                           name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
                                           object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardWillHideForResizing),
                                           name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                           object: nil)
}
// MARK: Keyboard Scroll
func keyboardWillShowForResizing(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        // We're not just minusing the kb height from the view height because
        // the view could already have been resized for the keyboard before
        // I need to get the bottom constraint and set it equal to keyboardSize.height

    } else {
        debugPrint("We're showing the keyboard and either the keyboard size or window is nil: panic widely.")
    }
}
func keyboardWillHideForResizing(notification: Notification) {
    //commentViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
}
```

This is my code for how I set up my view with all the textField components, including inputsContainerView:

```
 // MARK: Creation for TextFields
    let nameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Name"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()
    let nameSeparatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    let emailTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Email"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()
    let emailSeparatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Password"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    }()
    lazy var loginRegisterSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.tintColor =  UIColor.white
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }()
    //MARK: Change Button (Login/Register)
    func handleLoginRegisterChange() {
        let title = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState())

        // change height of inputContainerView, but how???
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.constant = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 100 : 150

        // change height of nameTextField
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 0 : 1/3)
        // Hides name placeholder when selected imdex is selected
        if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            nameTextField.placeholder = ""
        }
        else {
            nameTextField.placeholder = "Username"
        }
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor = emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
    }
    func setupLoginRegisterSegmentedControl() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true
    }
    func setupProfileImageView() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    }
    var inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var nameTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var emailTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    func setupInputsContainerView() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor = inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameSeparatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(emailTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(emailSeparatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(passwordTextField)

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        nameTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        nameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

        nameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        nameSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        emailTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        emailTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor = emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)

        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        emailSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        passwordTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
    }
    func setupLoginRegisterButton() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        loginRegisterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inputsContainerView sets it's Y position with this constraint

```
inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Which puts it in the view's center.

There is no bottom constraint set.

The first thing you need to do is to save this constraint in a property (create a var inputsYConstraint property)

```
inputsYConstraint = inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
inputsYConstraint.isActive = true
```

The easiest thing to do is set a negative constant on the constraint to move it up.

Alternatively, you could lower the priority of this constraint, and add a bottom constraint that you set a minimum on that you change when the keyboard comes up.

Comment: Thank you for the help, what do you mean by set a negative constant on the constraint to move it up? How would I do this? I originally wanted to set it equal to the keyboardSize.height ...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nslayoutconstraint The type of inputsYConstraint is NSLayoutConstraint.  It has a property named "constant" which would move this view up if you set to a negative number (it  would mean, center it vertically minus some number)

Comment: I have created the variable... Where would I make it = to a negative number?